# Как занести все матрицы в List

Tags: c#

Мне нужно реализовать чтение/запись 5ти матриц в bin-файл,каждая матрица должна иметь свой индекс.
Создаю матрицы отак

```
     Console.Write("Матриця на NxN = ");
     int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     Matrix A = new Matrix(n, n);
     Matrix B = new Matrix(n, n);
     Matrix Q = new Matrix(n, n);
     Matrix W = new Matrix(n, n);
     Matrix E = new Matrix(n, n);

    public class Saver
{
    /// <summary>Закрытый конструктор - его можно вызвать только в самом классе.</summary>
    private Saver() { }
    /// <summary>Единственный доступный экземпляр.</summary>
    public static Saver Instance { get; } = new Saver();

    /// <summary>Бинарный сериализатор.</summary>
    private static BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    /// <summary>Статический список со всеми матрицами.</summary>
    private static readonly List<int[,]> matrices = new List<int[,]>();

    /// <summary>Свойство экземпляра возвращающее все матрицы.<br/>
    /// Можно использовать с индексатором.</summary>
    public List<int[,]> Matrices => matrices;

    /// <summary>Приватный статический метод бинарной сериализации списка матриц.</summary>
    /// <param name="matrResult">Файл в который будет происходить сериализация.</param>
    private static void SaveToBin(string matrResult)
    {
        using (FileStream file = File.Create(matrResult))
            formatter.Serialize(file, matrices);
    }

    /// <summary>Приватный статический метод бинарной десериализации списка матриц.</summary>
    /// <param name="matrResult">Файл из которого будет происходить десериализация.</param>
    private static void LoadFromBin(string matrResult)
    {

        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(matrResult))
        {
            IEnumerable<int[,]> list = (IEnumerable<int[,]>)formatter.Deserialize(file);
            matrices.Clear();
            foreach (int[,] matrix in list)
                matrices.Add(matrix);
        }
    }

    public string matrResult { get; set; }

    public void Load() => LoadFromBin(matrResult);
    public void Save() => SaveToBin(matrResult);



}
```

класс Saver, в котором будет реализовано сохранение всех необходимых рабочих матриц, а также их чтения по определенному номеру.
Класс должен быть реализован с соблюдением паттерна программирования "Одиночка"
**Как занести все матрицы в List**

Comment: Как вы себе предполагаете формат файла, чтобы указывать только имя файла и иметь возможность прочитать его и распарсить? Не вижу описание формата, вижу только странное "матрицу вставить в свободную часть файла" - и вот тут у меня сразу вопросы: вы предполагаете "один файл - одна матрица"? Что по-вашему является свободной частью файла, как определить?

Comment: я перепутал, мне нужно реализовать чтение/запись 5ти матриц в bin-файл,каждая матрица должна иметь свой индекс

Comment: Это вы сами придумываете формат записи в файл? Если сами - то опишите, если не сами - тоже опишите, потому что пока неясно, что и как вы хотите сделать, но похоже вы сами этого не понимаете -- и пока не поймёте у вас  будут проблемы с написанием кода. Не стоит перекладывать их на нас: если вы думаете, что если вы плохо понимаете, что хотите сделать кто-то угадает... так себе затея. Хочу то, не знаю чего. Кодирую то, не понимаю что. Итог - что-то вы сделаете, но будет ли это то, что вы хотели - вряд ли.

Comment: т.к. вы не ответили на пост [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192774/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-bin-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb#comment2080034_1192774), то осмелюсь предположить, что вам нужен формат файла, хранящий кол-во матриц, матрицы(1 матрица = кол-во срок и столбцов + значения).

Comment: @AK Создать класс Saver, в котором будет реализовано сохранение всех необходимых рабочих матриц, а также их чтения по определенному номеру. Класс должен быть реализован с соблюдением паттерна программирования "Одиночка"

Методы класса:

открыть или создать указанный файл для записи \ чтения матриц;
записать матрицу в первую найденную достаточное по размеру свободную часть файла

Comment: прочитать матрицу с заданным номером из файла в память;
заменить записанную матрицу в файле на другую, если размер новой матрицы больше, записать ее в конец файла;
удалить матрицу;
удалить из файла пустые места (дефрагментация;
записать матрицу;
очистить файл матриц;

Comment: @return уже ответил више

Comment: Придумайте-всё-за-меня-я-сам-не-понимаю-задачу?

Comment: @AK это вы так окрестили это задание как домашку?

Comment: посмотрел я тут исходники, "их легче будет назвать безисходниками", т.к. ваш `namespace lab1_2` не даёт мне права дать ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @return ну что ж поделать, что у меня в универе "Анализ требований и паттерны проектирования", я просто веб-программирования в основном учу

Comment: Классы `BinaryReader` и `BinaryWriter` и `File` к вашим услугам. По поводу куда писать, создайте заголовочные данные, в которых запишите количество матриц, начало и размер каждой в байтах.